# Can Gmail favicons be customized by domain?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email

I have several different Gmail accounts with different domains (my school, my employer, etc.).  Is there a way to have each show a different favicon so I can know which browser tab is for which?  Chrome is my preferred browser, but Firefox is also good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through another source, I found these Chrome extensions to change the favicon:

- [I hate your favicon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/i-hate-your-favicon/laggbmpbikikiablknnppgglelkncemk?hl=en)
- [Tab Edit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-edit/hnpmcokdebcinajfhhnlgpijgaapkopp#)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the [Gmail Favicon Customizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-favicon-customizer/hbnnphjhkbdeagbpjcnihdgianfhdgoo) Chrome extension. Too bad these solutions are limited to Google Chrome.

[image]